# issues with next js and gobal fonts

Tags: fonts, next.js, tailwind-css, webfonts

I'm fairly new to Tailwind and would like some assistance with applying global fonts to my website. I would like to add a new font family (Roboto and Muli) as opposed to the one provided by default.

Currently, I have edited the global.css file to this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  body {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
}
```

It works fine on desktop however on mobile the font switches to a different one. How do I make sure the fonts stay the same?

I'm using Next.js.

Any assistance will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to [override font](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#font-families) in Tailwind config itself. So that font is not overridden whenever you use `font-sans` class.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  // other config ...
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: { sans: ['Roboto', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans] },
    },
  },
};
```

Then in `global.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html,
  body {
    @apply font-sans;
  }
}
```

Make sure your (web)font CSS is properly loaded (put the link tag in `_app.js`/`_document.js`). Refer [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#usage).

If in some component font is not being applied properly, then it means something has set different font. To fix this, try adding/applying `font-sans` class to the component.

Answer (score 0):

create a css file as below and import it into _app.txs or _app.js

```
body, html{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using NextJs and my current way of doing it is this:

```
/styles/global.scss

body {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  @apply text-black;
}

/pages/_app.jsx

import 'styles/global.scss';

.
.
.
<Head>
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;600&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
</Head>
.
.
.
```